# how to assign a new value to a variable in django

Tags: python, django, html, django-templates, django-views

I have the following array in my source code:

```
values: [
    {
          "Question" :  ["question two"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["answer to question 2"]} 
     ,          {
          "Question" :  ["question one"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["answer to question one"] } 
     ,          {
          "Question" :  ["question one"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["another answer to question one"]}
```

I need to render the information as a `ListView` to make it look like this:

> question two
>   answer to question 2
>   question one
>   answer to question one
>   another answer to question one

I'm using Django and HTML for rendering the view, here's my code so far

```
     <div>
     {% with "" as name %}  
     {% for value in view.data.values %}
     <li> 
        {% ifnotequal value.Question name %}
            <div>{{value.Question|default:''}}  {{value.question_creation_date}}</div>
         {% endifnotequal %}
            <div>{{value.user_creation_date}} {{value.Answer}}</div>
     </li>
      <!-- set name equal to value.Question -->
      {% endfor%}
      {% endwith %}
     </div>
```

How it is possible to do show the `ListView`?

Comment: Where is your question ?

Comment: I want to know how can i display the information as a list view like the example above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python not have array 
Python have list, dict, tuple
Now look your code you have this:
`values: [
    {
          "Question" :  ["question two"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["answer to question 2"]} 
     ,          {
          "Question" :  ["question one"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["answer to question one"] } 
     ,          {
          "Question" :  ["question one"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["another answer to question one"]}` 
This not correct !
You have missed ] in end of you code !

Second look again you say ==> `values: [
    {
          "Question" :  ["question two"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["answer to question 2"]} 
     ,          {
          "Question" :  ["question one"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["answer to question one"] } 
     ,          {
          "Question" :  ["question one"]   ,    "Answer" :  ["another answer to question one"]}`

that's a list of dict because you have value=[dict_0, dict_1, ...]

Now supose that you renturn it in a view ! To render it you can do something like this :  
`{% for v in values %}:
                <div class="question_answer">
                    <p class="line_question_answer">
                        <span class="question">
                           {% trans "question"%}: {{v.Question}}
                        </span>
                        <span class="answer">
                            {% trans "Answer" %}: {{v.Answer}}
                        </span>
                    </p>
                 </div>
 {% endfor %}`

Answer (score 1):

You have build data structure for it. And according to to it render it on template.

for e.g.

View code,

```
context = {}
values = [

{'question':'A','answer':'a'},
{'question':'B','answer':'b'},
{'question':'C','answer':'c'},
{'question':'D','answer':'d'},

]
context['values'] = values
```

Template Code,

```
{% for i in values %}
<p>
{{i.question}}
</br>
{{i.answer}}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

A `ListView` renders a list of objects from the database. Therefore, you will need to have a two models: one for `Question` and one for `Answer` (notice the use of singular).

```
from django.db import models

class Question(models.Model):
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)

class Answer(models.Model):
    question = models.OneToOneField(question)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Now that you have the model in place, we can use a `ListView` to render the view as follows:

```
from django.views.generic import ListView
from . import models

class MyView(ListView):
    model = Question
```

Then create a template in the following folder in your app: `templates/appname/templates/question_list.html` with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <p>
  {% for question in object_list %}
      {{ question.text }}<br>
      {{ question.answer.text }}
  {% empty %}
    No questions found.
  {% endfor %}
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Finally, include a `URLconf` in the main `urls.py` file with the following line:

```
from appname.views import MyView
...
url(r'^myapp/$', MyView.as_view()),
...
```

That should get you started.
Anyone with corrections to add?